# Adding a setter in a child class when the parent didn't have one in Haxe

Tags: inheritance, setter, haxe

haxe 3.2.1, cpp.

I have a `class A` with variable `X`, and `class B extends class A`.

I want to make a hook so that whenever `X` is set on an instance of `class B`, `B.set_X()` is called.

This is possible if `A.X` already has a setter, by overriding its setter.  But `A.X` doesn't have a setter.  Is there a way to achieve this without modifying `class A`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear this is possible.
In the [old docs](http://old.haxe.org/ref/properties), it specifically states that properties (which are used to declare getters and setters), are a 'way to *declare* class fields'.

Additionally, I found an [old forum discussion](http://old.haxe.org/forum/thread/685) of this problem. Unless something has changed in the meantime (and I tried it in the suggested way, it's still nonfunctional), then it appears you will need a workaround, perhaps by adding an additional property to the subclass.

Comment: Thanks.  In the case of the workaround though, the original class won't know anything about it, so hooks of this type aren't possible that way, either.  The only workaround would be modifying `class A`.